# Ionic2 AngularJS2 -- NavController pushes previous page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

### Intro

I'm creating an ionic mobile application. Now I'm trying to create a master-detail relationship where I can see events. When I click on an event I want to see all the participants. I already got this working although it is a bit bugged.

**I'm sorry for long question but I don't know where the problem is so I posted quite a detailed question**

---

### The Problem

When I click on my Event (which has `(click)` attribute) my application will choose an event (it shows in Network tab of developer view - chrome) and it will load my webpage (it also shows in Network tab of developer view - chrome).

But the webpage doesn't show. It just loads. This is because my NavController pushes the current page (EvenementenPage) when I first click the button. But when it's pushed it saves the information and then can continue to the detail pag. As shown below in pictures:

[image: Events page]
**note: this is evenementen.html -- it loads event.html and 1 (JSON object) but doesn't show it**

[image: Detail page with object 1]

This is what happens when I click one event twice, Note in network activity it will just load `1` again, it will not load `event.html` again.

[image: Detail page showing 1 when selected 3]

This is what happens when I select a **different** event. Note that in network it loads `3`, but shows the contents of `1` (i guess because `event.html` is not loaded again). They have different names and birth dates.

---

### The code

**evenementen.html -- `(click)`**

```
<ion-header> 
  <ion-navbar>
    <button menuToggle>
    <ion-icon name='menu'></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title light>Quintor Evenementen</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content class="search" padding>
 <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let event of evenementen"   (click)='selectEvent(event.id)'>
      <ion-thumbnail item-left>
        <img src="img/quintor.png">
      </ion-thumbnail>
      <h2 [innerText]="event.titel" primary></h2>
      <p>Aantal deelnemers: {{event.deelnemers}}</p><p><ion-icon name='clock'></ion-icon> 29 August 2017</p>
      <ion-icon item-right
  name='arrow-dropright-circle'></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

---

**evenementen.ts -- `selectEvent()`**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { EventDetailComponent } from '../event-detail/event';
/*
  Class for Evenementen Overzicht.
*/
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/evenementen/evenementen.html',
})
export class EvenementenPage {
public http;
public evenementen;
public evenement:any;

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, @Inject(Http) httpService) {
    this.http = httpService;
    this.evenementen = [];
    this.getEvenementen();
  }

  getEvenementen(){
   this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/evenementen').subscribe((response) => {
     this.evenementen = (response.json());
   });
  }

  selectEvent(id : number){
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/evenementen/'+id).subscribe(res =>{
      this.evenement = res.json();
      this.goToEventDetail(this.evenement);
    });
  }

  goToEventDetail(eventParam){

    this.navCtrl.push(EventDetailComponent
    , {
      event: eventParam
    });
    this.evenement= null;
  }

}
```

---

**event.html -- detail page**

```
<ion-content>
    <h2>tile</h2>
    <h1> YASS </h1>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let deelnemer of eventObj.alleDeelnemers">
            <h1>{{deelnemer.naam}}</h1>
            <p>{{deelnemer.geboortedatum}}</p>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <button (click)="goBack()">Go back</button>
</ion-content>
```

---

### event.ts -- detail page

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavParams, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'event-detail',
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/event-detail/event.html'
})

export class EventDetailComponent {
    public eventObj:any;

    constructor(private navCtrl : NavController, public navParams : NavParams) {
         this.eventObj = navParams.get("event");
    }
    goBack(){
        this.navCtrl.pop();
    }

}
```

Comment: When i (in `goToEventDetail( )`) push TWICE it does go to the detail page but when I then go back, it will be bugged and I can't select anything else anymore

Comment: Problem seems to be that the NavController pushes the same page (EvenementenPage) when executing `goToEventDetail()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the `selector` is bugged withing `@Component` when using Ionic2. When using this function it does load the page but probably waits untill the `selector` is called. Which won't happen.

Removing the `selector` solved my issues.

Comment: More about this issue here: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/7979#issuecomment-273567549